# What method is called when an activity is created from a foreground service notification?

Tags: android, user-interface, persistence, foreground-service

I am working on a system that runs bluetooth/gps tasks as a foreground service.
At present if the app is minimised and opened again the UI state is retained,
However if the app is closed and it is opened from the service notification It returns to the correct activity but I do not have the same contents in textboxes/ same switch states etc.
Was planning to used sharedpreferences to retain this but was not sure which method to override when returning via notification?

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLifeCycle/article.html

The onPause() method is typically used to stop framework listeners and UI updates. The onStop() method is used to save application data. These methods are guaranteed to be called before the activity is terminated.

If the user switches back to application which has been terminated by the system, it is restarted. Also its activity stack is recreated. The onResume() is used to register again listeners and to trigger UI updates based on the saved data.

Expected more to this, will update answer if I find any issues.